# Oracle APEX - How to create popup LOV which contained multiple display values?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, lov

I am trying to create LOV in Oracle Apex 4.1 which would contain name and surname of employees and would return only his/hers id. The syntax which does not work looks like this :

```
 select
     FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME as display_value, 
     USER_ID as return_value 
 from ALL_USERS
 order by 1
```

This returns error : Wrong number of columns selected in the LOV SQL query. 
Any help or guidance how to tackle this problem greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use :

```
select
     FIRST_NAME || ', ' || LAST_NAME as display_value, 
     USER_ID as return_value 
 from ALL_USERS
 order by 1
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to Vincent's solution, you can also look into this plugin:[SkillBuilders Super LOV](http://apex-plugin.com/oracle-apex-plugins/item-plugin/skillbuilders-super-lov_75.html)
It allows for multiple columns, multiple column return, and simply looks good.
The only downside is there is no tabular form option for this. (yet. It is a plugin limitation)